# Alarm Manager repeat abnormally with in Service

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I created simple service that have to Log every one second. I used alarm manager(because  from [official document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) says`Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running.`) but it repeating randomly. 
Here is my code

**MainActiviry.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        if (fab != null) {
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LogService.class);
                    startService(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I start service by click on FAB button.

**LogService.class**

```
public class LogService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = LogService.class.getSimpleName();

    public LogService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand: Service calling" );

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Timer(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void Timer(Context context){
        Intent  intent = new Intent(context,LogService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,0,intent,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(alarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),1*1000,pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Here is my *LOG*

[image: Logcat]

It repeating every minute,but I write every second. Does i make any wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since API 19 repeating alarms are **inexact**. See this:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

You would have to set your `targetSdkVersion` to a lower value than 19 or use one-time exact alarms and re-set them every time.

This is the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Simple solution with `java.util.Timer`

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Put your code here
                    Log.d("Log", "Hello World");
                }
            }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: but [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)  says `Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running.` so i used it, can you show sample for one-time exact alarms ?

Comment: If you just want a simple timer doing something every second, you could use the java Timer class too. Another solution are Handlers, depends on what you really want to do

Comment: yah, Thanks  I will use simple handler, is there any chance to achieve this with alarm manager ?

Comment: Yes, but it is probably not that efficient and the best solution for frequently repeating actions, like counting stuff. I can give you some examples in my answer